# This script in python is causing a segmentation fault when the input is a binary tree with 14 levels (32767 vertex)

Tags: python, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

The edges are in a list of string: ["Origin1 Destination1" "Origin2 Destination2"...]
The program does the job in smaller tests, but when it tries to run for a 14 level binary-tree, it fails and says segmentation fault.

```
def AdjVtc(vertex, lstObjVtx, lstEdges):
    adj = []
    for edge in lstEdges:
        edg = edge.split(" ")
        origin = edg[0]
        destination = edg[1]
        if origin == vertex.getName():
            for vertexSearch in lstObjVtx:
                if vertexeSearch.getName() == destination:
                    if vertexSearch.getColor() != 2:
                        adj.append(vertexSearch)
                    break

    return adj




def bfs(lstVertex, lstEdges):

    lstObjVtx = []
    for a in lstVertex:

        vertex = Vertex(a, 0)
        lstObjVtx.append(vertex)


    lstObjVtx[0].setCor(1)
    lstObjVtx[0].setD(0)
    queue = []
    queue.append(lstObjVtx[0])
    print (lstObjVtx[0].getName(), end = " ")
    print (lstObjVtx[0].getName(), end = " ")
    print (0)
    while queue != []:
        actual = queue.pop(0)

        lstAdj = AdjVtx(actual, lstObjVtx, lstEdges)
        for adjacent in lstAdj:
            if adjacent.getColor() == 0:
                adjacent.setD(atual.getD() + 1)
                adjacent.setFather(atual)
                adjacent.setColor(1)
                queue.append(adjacent)
                print (lstObjVtx[0].getName(), end = " ")
                print (adjacent.getNome(), end = " ")
                print (adjacent.getD(), end = "\n")

        actual.setColor(2)
```